# Addressing "Undefined property: stdClass::" properly

Tags: php, json

Here is my issue, I am aware why this is happening but, I am unsure how to resolve it as my research on this issue hasn't returned anything valid to my certain issue.

I am making a cURL request and parsing the objects to get their value and then storing it in a variable to insert into a DB later. The HTTP request is from a streaming server. With that said if the stream is not active the object is not present but, if the object is present it is returned like so...

```
<IsConnected>true</IsConnected>
```

So in my script I have been parsing the object like so to find if the value of the object is true or false then storing that value in a variable to insert into a DB.

```
$streamStatus = $obj->isConnected?'true':'false';
```

While this works great, it is not correct syntax because when the object is not present due to the stream not being active then I get the following errors in my error log by the dozens.

> Undefined property: stdClass::$isConnected

So my question is, how can I can I properly address this so I can get it's value of true when it is active and the object is present but false when the object is not present?

**EDIT**

Here is the full response if the stream is active and what is returned by the request.

```
<IncomingStream serverName="_defaultServer_">
<ApplicationInstance>_definst_</ApplicationInstance>
<Name>ncopeland</Name>
<SourceIp>rtmp://xx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxxxx</SourceIp>
<IsRecordingSet>false</IsRecordingSet>
<IsStreamManagerStream>false</IsStreamManagerStream>
<IsPublishedToVOD>false</IsPublishedToVOD>
<IsConnected>true</IsConnected>
<IsPTZEnabled>false</IsPTZEnabled>
<PtzPollingInterval>2000</PtzPollingInterval>
</IncomingStream>
```

Comment: Why don't you print out $obj to see what is stored in that variable? 

Use print_r() as it shows a nice organised result.

Comment: I already know what is stored. The issue is checking if the object is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> While this works great, it is not correct syntax because when the object is not present

Then simply add the check for object validity prior interacting with it:

```
$streamStatus = (is_object($obj) && property_exists($obj, 'isConnected') && $obj->isConnected) ? 'true' : 'false';
```

NOTE that other answers may suggest using `isset()` for the above but this is wrong as `isset()` is not correct tool for the task due to the fact how it handles `null`.

Comment: You make a very valid point regarding using isset(). I will give this a try as well.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
$streamStatus = (isset($obj->isConnected) && $obj->isConnected)?'true':'false';
```

Comment: Yes, isset that is what I was looking for but wasn't sure how to apply it in this situation. Let me test this and I will report back but, I think this should do the trick.